# I want to know why "Word('zhiying') == Word('navaln')" is true?

Tags: python, class

In the python console, I define a class named Word.

```
class Word(str):
    def __new__(cls, word):
        if ' ' in word:
            print("Value contains spaces.Truncating to first space.")
            word = word[:word.index(' ')]
            return str.__new__(cls,word)
    def __gt__(self, other):
        return len(self) > len(other)
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return len(self) < len(other)
    def __ge__(self, other):
        return len(self) >= len(other)
    def __le__(self, other):
        return len(self) <= len(other)
```

I want to know why that output of `Word('zhiying') == Word('navaln')` is true?

[image]

Comment: Try and see what `type(Word('zhiying'))` is…!?

Answer (score 6):

Because your `__new__` method returns `None` for any word with no space in it. Probably you want to unindent the `return` statement. You can even see this problem in your console output -- when you try `len(Word('zhiying'))` you get an error about `NoneType`.

Comment: I have tried len（Word（'zhiying'））and got an Error of “TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has No len（）”.